# what is the meaning of these linker errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, static-libraries

I wish I could ask "What libraries do i need to link" but it's quite specific (wwise engine integration), so I need help in working it out myself. The problem occurs when I attempt to create a variable of a type defined in a header file (compiler finds the header no problem). I get 22 linker errors but I don't understand the read out, could someone walk me through it and tell me precisely which symbol is missing so I can figure out what libraries I'm missing? and could it be anything other than a library not linking? Wwise comes with a demo project that compiles but doesnt link to any more libraries than I do.

Here are 5 of the errors. I'm using visual studio.

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: enum AKRESULT __thiscall CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking::Init(struct AkDeviceSettings const &,bool)" (?Init@CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking@@QAE?AW4AKRESULT@@ABUAkDeviceSettings@@_N@Z) referenced in function "bool __cdecl InitSoundEngine(void)" (?InitSoundEngine@@YA_NXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking::GetDeviceDesc(struct AkDeviceDesc &)" (?GetDeviceDesc@CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking@@UAEXAAUAkDeviceDesc@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned long __thiscall CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking::GetDeviceData(void)" (?GetDeviceData@CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking@@UAEKXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual enum AKRESULT __thiscall CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking::Read(struct AkFileDesc &,struct AkIoHeuristics const &,void *,struct AkIOTransferInfo &)" (?Read@CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking@@UAE?AW4AKRESULT@@AAUAkFileDesc@@ABUAkIoHeuristics@@PAXAAUAkIOTransferInfo@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual enum AKRESULT __thiscall CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking::Write(struct AkFileDesc &,struct AkIoHeuristics const &,void *,struct AkIOTransferInfo &)" (?Write@CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking@@UAE?AW4AKRESULT@@AAUAkFileDesc@@ABUAkIoHeuristics@@PAXAAUAkIOTransferInfo@@@Z)
```

Comment: As the error mentions, there are several symbols missing (all from the `CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking` class): `Init`, `GetDeviceDesc`, `GetDeviceData`, `Read`, and `Write`.  Whatever libary or object file(s) would contain the implementation of the `CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking` class is what you're looking for. A google search gets hits for something called 'gmwwise': https://code.google.com/p/gmwwise/

Comment: I hope you're not linking x86 libraries in a project that targets x64.

Comment: as far as i know everything is x86.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbols are:

```
enum AKRESULT CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking::Init(struct AkDeviceSettings const &,bool)
virtual void CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking::GetDeviceDesc(struct AkDeviceDesc &)
virtual unsigned long CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking::GetDeviceData(void)
virtual enum AKRESULT CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking::Read(struct AkFileDesc &,struct AkIoHeuristics const &,void *,struct AkIOTransferInfo &)
virtual enum AKRESULT CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking::Write(struct AkFileDesc &,struct AkIoHeuristics const &,void *,struct AkIOTransferInfo &)
```

As far as I can tell, you only have the header that declares the class `CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking`, which means that you attempt to use any of the above symbols you'll need to link against the library.

> Wwise comes with a demo project that compiles but doesnt link to any more libraries than I do.

Either the symbols aren't used, or the source files that defines those symbols is compiled in that project - http://gmwwise.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/GMWwise/wwise/AkDefaultIOHookBlocking.cpp

Comment: did you work that out based on the readout CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking::Init for example, did that tell you that the declaration as missing implementation? i added the CAkDefaultIOHookBlocking.cpp to the project which cleared up some of the errors but I still have 13 of them which are similar. if one of them were "CAkFileLocationBase::CAkFileLocationBase(void)" ..." would that mean the implementation for CAkFileLocationBase is mising somewhere?

Comment: thanks, it worked. for anyone reading this having searched how to integrate wwise, you need to add all files in samples/soundengine to the project. its not enough to just #include the default I/O file.

Comment: either that or link to the soundendine.dll as the cube project does.

Answer (score 2):

You have a file `AkDefaultIOHookBlocking.cpp` that hasn't been added to the project you're building.